# What are fortunes?

Tags: r

In R, one sometime sees people making references to fortunes.  For example:

```
fortune(108)
```

What does this mean?  Where does this originate?  Where can I get the code?

**Edit.**  The sharp-eyed reader would have noticed that this question marks the `5,000th` question with the [r] tag.  Forgive the frivolity, but such a milestone should be marked with a bit of humour.  For an extra bit of fun, you can provide an answer with your favourite `fortune` cookie.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It refers to the `fortunes` package, which is a package that contains a whole set of humorous quotes and comments from the help lists, conferences, fora and even StackOverflow.

It is actually a database or small dataframe you can browse through.

```
library(fortunes)
fortune()
```

To get a random one. Or look for a specific one, eg :

```
> fortune("stackoverflow")

datayoda: Bing is my friend...I found the cumsum() function.
Dirk Eddelbuettel: If bing is your friend, then rseek.org is bound 
to be your uncle.
   -- datayoda and Dirk Eddelbuettel (after searching for a function that 
      computes cumulative sums)
      stackoverflow.com (October 2010)
```

If you want to get all of them in a dataframe, just do

```
MyFortunes <- read.fortunes()
```

The numbers sometimes referred to, are the row numbers of this dataframe. To find everything on stackoverflow :

```
> grep("(?i)stackoverflow",MyFortunes$source)
[1] 273 275
> fortune(275)

I used a heuristic... pulled from my posterior. That makes it Bayesian, right?
   -- JD Long (in a not too serious chat about modeling strategies)
      Stackoverflow (November 2010)
```

Answer (score 12):

And for the record, 108 is is this one:

```
R> library(fortunes)
R> fortune(108)

Actually, I see it as part of my job to inflict R on people who are 
perfectly happy to have never heard of it. Happiness doesn't equal 
proficient and efficient. In some cases the proficiency of a person 
serves a greater good than their momentary happiness.
   -- Patrick Burns
      R-help (April 2005)

R>
```

Answer (score 6):

They're humorous (sometimes snarky) comments collected from the R lists.

```
install.packages("fortunes")
```

Or more generally

```
install.packages("sos")
library("sos")
findFn("fortune")
```

Comment: +1 Ben, you win the prize for answering the 5,000th question on SO with the [r] tag.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/) turns up the [`fortunes` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/index.html), which basically just prints random witty quotes related to R. The concept is based on the [`fortune` program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) from Unix.

Comment: Yes, but you may want [rseek.org](http://rseek.org) for more focussed R-related search.